# Statement in question form

Tags: sentence

> Learn to see, learn to hear, learn to feel, learn to smell and know that by practice alone will you become experts.

In the above sentence, why is "will you become experts" a statement?

Comment: It's an  auxiliary verb inverted with its subject, licensed by the initial negative _by practice alone_. It's a statement because it's not a question or an order.

Comment: Why did you say "the above" instead of "this" or "that"? It really doesn't sound normal.